# Grab Last matching item in NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsarray

I have a long NSMutableArray of a piece of text separated per word.

I am looking for a few keywords key words to perform actions, but the array may contain multiple of the keywords and I want it to only respond to the last keyword in the array and ignore all the ones it finds before that. What would be an efficient way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

Try using your array's `reverseObjectEnumerator`:

```
NSInteger index = [myArray length];
for (NSString *str in [myArray reverseObjectEnumerator]) {
    index -= 1;
    if ([str isEqualToString:@"theStringToTestFor"])
        break;
}
```

`index` should now contain the index of the last matching string in the array.

Comment: Would I need to add another if section for each string I'm searching for? And if so would it still stop after it found the first one?

Comment: @Prognastat Yes, you'd need to add another section per string (or use `||` in the `if` statement), and then it will stop on the first string in your array that matches one of the strings you're testing for.

Answer (score 1):

Search the array backwards.

```
NSArray* words;

[words enumerateObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationReverse usingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

    NSString* word = (NSString*)obj;

    if ([word isEqualToString:@"testString"])
        stop = YES;

}];
```